# Set the password for sql-postgres

Tags: sql, sql-mode

I have a question regarding connecting to a sql database programmatically. Ideally I would like to have a function with similar functionality to the `sql-postgres` but instead of interactively prompting me for each part of the connection string, I would just like to programmatically provide all of the arguments.

I seemed to make some progress by setting the defaults the database uses as follows:

```
    (setq sql-user url-user)
    (setq sql-server "localhost") 
    (setq sql-database "myDatabase")
    (setq sql-port db-port)
    (setq sql-password my-password)
    (call-interactively #'sql-postgres)
```

This gets me 90% the way there. The only thing missing is the prompt still asks me for my password and wont take the default I set. I was looking around for a workaround but I could't seem to figure it out. If there is a better way to go about this problem I would be glad to hear ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a duplicate of this S.O. question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26677909/emacs-sql-mode-postgresql-and-inputing-password

Your problem is that you *cannot* include the password as part of the `psql` command, so this (generic) functionality of Emacs' SQL support is not applicable to postgres.

Refer to the duplicate Q&A for lots of discussion and options.

See also:

- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/libpq-pgpass.html
- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/auth-methods.html